# Does Facebook offer ajax push or similar methods to avoid constant polling?

Tags: ios, facebook, push

I would like my app to receive updates to the logged in user's newsfeed without constantly polling for the current newsfeed to be returned to my app.

I see a lot of questions that are close to what I'm asking for but the one's I've checked are either never answered or have answers that are merely generalities providing no details nor pointers to where details can be obtained.

I'v heard that Facebook uses Comet and/or ajax push for its chat implementation but can it be made to use this for pushing newsfeed updates to my app? If so, is there some place where I can find examples of the use of the facebook API to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, This is possible by creating Push Notification app from the Facebook developers site. Create an app for pages and then u can connect to the pages using Graph API editor and also configure the notifications received by this application to be forwarded to a callback URL. Read The Real Time Push Notification document on Facebook developers.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. The Facebook Graph API does not support push notifications. You have to poll. The one alternative seems to be for Blackbery devices that recieve push notification of facebook updates. But i believe that is because RIM is doing the polling themselves and then pushing the notification to the device.

To the best of my knowledge, the only way to get info from the Graph API is to pull and poll.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i don't think this would be possible yet, given HTML is stateless, there's no way the server can post back to the clients, as the clients only get responses to their own requests from the server.

You'd need something that can establish a connection and listen on a port, that's the sort of length you'd have to go to (non-html based, embedded in the page)

I wonder if you could stagger out and slow down a server's response to an ajax request, so for example, the server doesn't finish responding to an ajax poll request for 30 seconds, but if during that time something happens, it has the ability to respond immediately... something to think about. I'm not sure how long a browser will wait for the response to come back, but you could exploit that by polling only once per time-out period.